# Using PHP Ajax to query ssllabs api

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl

After general advice, techniques or examples if possible.

I'm looking to integrate testing of URL's with SSLlabs API.
www.ssllabs.com/projects/ssllabs-apis/index.html

I've established the URL's that i need to execute to retrieve the info from this api.

e.g. Start analysis - https://api.ssllabs.com/api/v2/analyze?host=portal.testdomain.co.uk

Retrieve results - https://api.ssllabs.com/api/v2/getEndpointData?host=portal.testdomain.co.uk&s=10.111.222.234

My question is, how would i go about integrating into an Ajax/php site?
Or would this be better only executed on backend system and the results pumped into a DB?

So far, i have a button that simply grabs the contents of 2 hidden fields containing hostname and ip address to query.

```
function stateck() 
{
    if(httpxml.readyState==4 && httpxml.status == 200)
    {
    console.log(httpxml.responseText);
    alert(httpxml.responseText);
    }
}


var url="ssltest.php?commonname=" + commonname + "&s=" + ip;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
httpxml.open("GET", url, true);
httpxml.send(null);
```

The ssltest.php contains the following cURL function to query then return the api page content. Browsing to this ssltest.php with the parameters in the url works a treat.

```
@$commonname=$_GET['commonname'];
@$ip=$_GET['ip'];

if(is_numeric($commonname)){
    echo "Data Error";
    exit;
}

$testurl = "https://api.ssllabs.com/api/v2/analyze?host=" . $commonname;
$resulturl = "https://api.ssllabs.com/api/v2/getEndpointData?host=" . $commonname . "&s=" . $ip;

function ssl_test_start($url,$useragent='cURL',$headers=false,
                        $follow_redirects=false,$debug=false) {
    # initialise the CURL library
    $ch = curl_init();
    # specify the URL to be retrieved
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    # we want to get the contents of the URL and store it in a variable
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    # specify the useragent: this is a required courtesy to site owners
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    # ignore SSL errors
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    # return headers as requested
    if ($headers==true){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
    }
    # only return headers
    if ($headers=='headers only') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY ,1);
    }
    # follow redirects - note this is disabled by default in most PHP installs 
    from 4.4.4 up
        if ($follow_redirects==true) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    }
    # if debugging, return an array with CURL's debug info and the URL contents
    if ($debug==true) {
        $result['contents']=curl_exec($ch);
        $result['info']=curl_getinfo($ch);
    }
    # otherwise just return the contents as a variable
    else $result=curl_exec($ch);
    # free resources
    curl_close($ch);
    # send back the data
    return $result;
}

function ssl_test_results($url,$useragent='cURL',$headers=false,
                          $follow_redirects=false,$debug=false) {
    # initialise the CURL library
    $ch = curl_init();
    # specify the URL to be retrieved
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    # we want to get the contents of the URL and store it in a variable
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    # specify the useragent: this is a required courtesy to site owners
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    # ignore SSL errors
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    # return headers as requested
    if ($headers==true){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
    }
    # only return headers
    if ($headers=='headers only') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY ,1);
    }
    # follow redirects - note this is disabled by default in most PHP installs 
    from 4.4.4 up
        if ($follow_redirects==true) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    }
    # if debugging, return an array with CURL's debug info and the URL contents
    if ($debug==true) {
        $result['contents']=curl_exec($ch);
        $result['info']=curl_getinfo($ch);
    }
    # otherwise just return the contents as a variable
    else $result=curl_exec($ch);
    # free resources
    curl_close($ch);
    # send back the data
    return $result;
}

if (!isset($ip)){
    $result = ssl_test_start($testurl);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
else {
    $result = ssl_test_start($resulturl);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

How do i then get the $result back into the original page and then access/display the result values? I am currently attempting to use XMLHttpRequest() but responseText does not seem to contain anything.

Comment: "would this be better only executed on backend system and the results pumped into a DB?" Depends if you want the results now or later. But why can't you just make an ajax request directly to the API without your intermediary PHP script? Does it not support CORS?

Comment: Bit more digging has revealed that what I'm trying to accomplish is not within the SSLLabs terms of use. and CORS requests are prevented. https://community.qualys.com/thread/16956-how-to-use-ssl-labs-api-into-a-web-browser-from-javascript  . So looks like i'm only going to be able to do this with backend script.

Comment: responseText is only the end of the journey. You need to track right back through the code to find where it goes wrong. At some point, there is a place where you're either not sending a request properly, or not getting a proper response. Use a tool like Fiddler to trace what is actually happening when you make both your ajax request to PHP, and then your request to SSLLabs, and see what the requests and responses look like. If it's all ok, then you need to debug your code flow (e.g. by tracing variables etc.

Comment: If the requests to SSLLabs are not ok, then compare it to a browser request and see what the difference is - maybe you need to alter options in curl etc. If it's your ajax request that's a problem, then post the error/problem you're getting in the question and we can look at it. HTTP status code, any error response in your browser console, that sort of thing. From a brief glance there's nothing obviously wrong in your code, so it's probably some detail somewhere.

Comment: The only thing I'd say up front is, I don't know what goes into `commonname` and `ip` (though I can guess the latter!) and you're not URL-encoding them, so if there's any text in those that could be counted as special characters in a URL or querystring, or they contain spaces etc, then that could be causing the requests to fail or behave unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this worked out in the end.

In a nutshell i used jQuery GET method to pass to the backend php.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "ssltest.php",
  data: dataString,
  dataType: "json",

  success: function(response) {

  //Do something.

  }
})
```

Works a treat and easy to traverse through the resulting array sent back.